# Changing form from $.post request result

Tags: jquery, post, parent

here's my dilemma, I have a page, with a form on top. This form contains multiple checkboxes with the same name: "Topic". Each time I tick or untick one or more checkboxes it loads the resulting page in a div by using a $.post jquery request, like this:

```
$.post("index-main-list.php", $("#selectors").serialize(), function(data){
$('#main-list').html(data); });
```

my form id being "selectors" and the result being loaded in the "main-list" div.
So far, all of this works fine.

The page result loaded in the #main-list contains a list of articles corresponding to the topic the user chooses.

But in this list, every article has a link to his specific topic, what I would want those links to do, is to untick all boxes in the form that is on the page, and tick only the corresponding box, therefore triggering a new execution of the $.post request and therefore loading only the articles corresponding to the topic the user chose.

By using something like :

```
$('#selectors')[0].reset(); 
$('input[id=topic]').attr('checked', true);
```

But for some reason, I can't seem to change anything in the #selectors form, anyone might have an idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$('input:checked').attr('checked', false); // uncheck all checked
$('input[id=topic]').attr('checked', true); // check only the specific box
```

Also, if `#selectors` is your form, then this will be more specific and perform a bit better:

```
$('#selectors').find('input:checked').attr('checked', false);
$('#selectors').find('input[id=topic]').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, but the thing is I can't seem to perform any action on the form itself, not when I execute the code from the generate page that is loaded in the div. I was wondering if there's any rule preventing from jquery loaded by an ajax request having action on the page that loaded it?